# List sort based on another shorter list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to sort a list based on the order of the elements in another list which is shorter ie, doesn't have all the elements compared to the list I'm sorting. I run into this error when using the `sort(key=short_list)`:

```
long_list = ['y', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b']
short_list = ['b', 'c', 'a']
long_list.sort(key=short_list.index)

ValueError: 'x' is not in list
```

Is there another way to sort the `long_list` to result in a `list` that maintains the order of `short_list` followed by the order of the elements in the `long_list`?

```
['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'z', 'x']
```

Comment: What does *like this* mean? Do you want to keep the relative order of `long_list` or `short_list`?

Comment: So if `short_list = ['b', 'a', 'c']`, then the sorted long list would be `long_list= ['b', 'a', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']`?

Comment: @JoePatten yes that is what I would like to maintain in the resulting list.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer updated the question to be more clear about whats expected.

Comment: Updated the code sample to be more clear, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in` to detect if the element is in the short_list and a ternary to return a tuple based on that.:

```
>>> long_list = ['y', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>> short_list = ['b', 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(long_list, key=lambda e: (short_list.index(e),e) if e in short_list  else (len(short_list),e))
['b', 'c', 'a', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Since Python sorts are stable, the order will only change based on a change of the elements themselves. To make that change, we can use a tuple with either a `(index_of_the_element, element)` of `(len(short_list), element)` to effect that change.

If you want the elements to not change order if the element is not in short list, just return an empty tuple:

```
>>> sorted(long_list, key=lambda e: (short_list.index(e),e) if e in short_list  else (len(short_list),))
['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'z', 'x']
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
def position(value):
    try:
        return short_list.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return len(short_list)

long_list.sort(key=position)
```

[Sorting is guaranteed to be stable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), so using `len(short_list)` ensures that the unknown values sort last.

Comment: Slick use of sorting stability.

Answer (score 2):

I would search in the short list first and in the long list if necessary:

```
>>> def index(list1, list2):
...  def inner(value):
...   try:
...    return list1.index(value)
...   except ValueError:
...    return list2.index(value)
... 
>>> long_list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> short_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> long_list.sort(key=index(short_list, long_list))
>>> long_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Edit: as florian-weimer [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545157/python-list-sort-based-on-another-shorter-list/52545318#comment92030678_52545318), this solution does not always work. Joining the two solutions:

```
>>> def index(list1, list2):
...  def inner(value, l=len(list1)):
...   try:
...    return list1.index(value)
...   except ValueError:
...    return l
...  return inner
... 
>>> long_list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> short_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y']
>>> sorted(long_list, key=index(short_list, long_list))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'x', 'z']
>>>
```

Comment: I've never thought about using a closure for a key function before, I quite like the idea.

Comment: Does this really work? `long_list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']` and `short_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y']` appears to be a counter-example.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, good catch; the index from the longer list is smaller than the index of the shorter list; best idea would probably be to use `len(list1) + list2.index(value)`, but then you might as well just use `len(list1)` as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what i'm doing here is i am first sorting elements of long_list by their index in short_list. If the element is not in short_list, I'll assign them all the same value of len(short_list). While sorting, if the first_sort is the same for two elements, it'll sort by second_sort which is the position in the long_list.
lets look at each case

1. 'a', 'b'  and 'c' are all sorted by their position in short_list. If there are repetitions of 'a', 'b' or 'c' in long_list, then they are sorted by their respective positions. So you'll get ['b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'].
2. 'y', 'z', 'x' get sorted first by len(short_list). This puts them last compared to the elements in the short list. Then they get sorted in the order they come in long_list.

Key takeaways:

1. You can pass a function to key that will let you sort according to any function.
2. You can pass a function that returns multiple values, so that any ties in the first value are resolved by the second value and so on.

```
long_list = ['y', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b']
short_list = ['b', 'c', 'a']

def sorter(x):
    if x in short_list:
        first_sort = short_list.index(x)
    else:
        first_sort = len(short_list)
    second_sort = long_list.index(x)
    return first_sort, second_sort

print(sorted(long_list, key=sorter))
```

```
['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'z', 'x']
```